# how to get the variable from my list in flutter

Tags: flutter, output

when i want to select from my list i don't get the variable just this msg : Instance of Vocabulary.

```
color: (_selectedItems.contains(HomePage.vocabularyList[index])) ? Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5) : Colors.transparent,
                   //select and import to a category
                      child: ListTile(
                        //to remove
                        onTap: (){
                        if(_selectedItems.contains(HomePage.vocabularyList[index])){
                        setState(() {
                        _selectedItems.removeWhere((val) => val == HomePage.vocabularyList[index]);
                        });}},
                        //to add
                        onLongPress: (){
                         //print(HomePage.vocabularyList[index].CategoryId);
                        if(! _selectedItems.contains(HomePage.vocabularyList[index])){
                        setState(() {
                        _selectedItems.add(HomePage.vocabularyList[index]);
                        print(HomePage.vocabularyList[index]);
                        });}
                        },
                        title: _showWords(index),
              ),);
```

and output is:

```
I/flutter (  338): Instance of 'Vocabulary'
```

Comment: what is your vocabularyList items type?

Comment: Don't post screenshot of your code, rather paste the relevant part of it here.

Comment: @quoci i corrected this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `Vocabulary` class doesn't have a `.toString()` method.
You can try to display one of the properties of your class by using

`print(Homepage.vocabularyList.elementAt(index).word);`

Where `word` is `String` property of your `Vocabulary` class

Answer (score 0):

In order to print an object you should override the [toString()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-core/Object/toString.html) method. Sample code:

```
class Vocabulary{
  int id;
  String text;
  String language;
  Vocabulary(this.id,  this.text, this.language);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Vocabulary{id: $id, text: $text, language: $language}';
  }
}
```